What happens if a player isn't riding a machine at the end of City Trial?
In City Trial mode, whatever machine a player is riding at the end of the city wandering phase gets used in the final battle round. What happens if a player isn't on a machine when the city phase ends? Is there a fallback machine that gets provided?

If a player's machine is destroyed by an attack such as a bomb or another player and time runs out they will be given a Compact Star in the Stadium game.
You can tell this is the case if the HUD in the bottom right corner shows a broken boost meter.

If a player jumps off a machine willingly (by pulling down the control stick and holding the boost button) and time runs out they will be given the machine they had last used in the Stadium game.
Here the HUD will show your player color instead.
Should your machine be destroyed whilst you are on foot you will also be given a Compact Star.

